# what is the parameter bool in APInt(unsigned numBits, uint64_t val, bool isSigned = false) used for?

Tags: c++, llvm

I am curious about the third paramter, the boolean `isSigned` in `APInt(unsigned numBits, uint64_t val, bool isSigned = false)` from LLVMs [`llvm/ADT/APInt.h` header](https://llvm.org/doxygen/APInt_8h_source.html).

No matter what I set it to, the result of functions like `getActiveBits()` or `getMinSignedBits()` does not change at all.

Furthermore if I want get an signed/unsigned value, I use `getSExtValue()` or `getZExtValue()`.

The value of `isSigned` does not matter to them either.

So when will `isSigned` matter?

Comment: I guess, when you are actually storing a negative value inside. But that's a guess only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `isSigned` is only important for `numBits > 64`.

The `sizeof(val)` is only 64 bits. Imagine you want to store a signed value in a integer with a `size > 64 bits`.

- If the value is negativ, all high bits must be set to `1` since negative values are typically stored as [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).
- If the value is positive, all high bits must be set to `0`

### Example

Let's assume you want to store **-1** in 128 bits.

The binary representation of `uint64_t val` holding **-1** is

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

This are only 64 ones, so there are 64 bits left to be filled. Without the `isSigned` value, it would be impossible to know whether these bits should be **ones**, resulting in **-1** or **zeros**, resulting in **18446744073709551615**.

### Long explanation

A look a the [source code](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/7214b3f52885ad5351fed6d75535d229334aaac9/include/llvm/ADT/APInt.h#L277) reveals, that `isSigned` is only used under certain circumstances:

```cpp
APInt(unsigned numBits, uint64_t val, bool isSigned = false)
     : BitWidth(numBits) {
   assert(BitWidth && "bitwidth too small");
   if (isSingleWord()) {
       U.VAL = val;
       clearUnusedBits();
   } else {
       initSlowCase(val, isSigned);
   }
}
```

According to [its function header](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/include/llvm/ADT/APInt.h#L114), `isSingleWord`

> returns true if the number of bits <= 64, false otherwise.

Therefore the line

```cpp
if (isSingleWord()) {
```

checks if the storage for the value occupies more memory than `val` itself.

If `numBits` is larger than 64, [`APInt::initSlowCase`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/lib/Support/APInt.cpp#L77) gets called:

```cpp
void APInt::initSlowCase(uint64_t val, bool isSigned) {
   U.pVal = getClearedMemory(getNumWords());
   U.pVal[0] = val;
   if (isSigned && int64_t(val) < 0)
       for (unsigned i = 1; i < getNumWords(); ++i)
           U.pVal[i] = WORDTYPE_MAX;
   clearUnusedBits();
}
```

This function copies the value from the `val` variable and fills the bits to `numBits`.

That is necessary, because begative values are stored as two's complement.  If `isSigned` is set and `val` is a negative value, all bits of the high words are set to ones.

Comment: So `isSigned` only matters if I pass an `uint64_t val` which is negative while the `unsigned numBits` is bigger than 64, right?

Comment: I've updated [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57471295/11562913), would you please take a loot at it?

Answer (score 1):

Acording to the [docs](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1APInt.html#a6286f2ba84c5ad11f4a90d57cb1dd293) is tells if `val` is signed or unsigned.

> If isSigned is true then val is treated as if it were a signed value (i.e. as an int64_t) and the appropriate sign extension to the bit width will be done. Otherwise, no sign extension occurs (high order bits beyond the range of val are zero filled).